# How do I redraw UICollectionView when MvxCollectionViewSource's data changes?

Tags: data-binding, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I am using Xamarin and MVVMCross to implement an IOS app. A view I'm working on is displaying correctly, but ONLY when I hard-code the data being bound to inside my ViewModel and NOT when (as by design and necessity) my data arrives late from SQLite, only an indeterminate time after the view is shown.

What I am using and accomplished so far:

- Working/Showing storyboard for my View that has a *UICollectionView*
  inside (called: **CollectionView** in code below)
- Custom layout and XIB file for every *UICollectionViewCell* that also displays correctly in my view
- A view that works and displays correctly only if ViewModel data is fully populated the moment *ViewDidLoad()* is called.

Problem:

- My data in my **ViewModel** is updated by the Model's databases in an uncertain amount of time whilst the view is happily being shown. When I bind the data as shown below (and trying two-way/one-way bindings and the like as well), I don't get updates on my view as the **final data** comes in later.

What I can't seem to do:

- Redraw the *UICollectionView* or maybe refresh the
  *MvxCollectionViewSource* below to ensure that as the ViewModel's data changes, I can actually redraw the *UICollectionView* and show my
  custom cells with new and updated data.

**THE CODE(TM)**

The *CollectionView* cells are implemented as follows. I followed all examples online and from that Stuart Bloke and his Kittens to make sure I implement all the patterns exactly the same:

```
[Register("MyCell")]
public partial class MyCell : MvxCollectionViewCell
{
    public static readonly UINib Nib = UINib.FromName("MyCell", NSBundle.MainBundle);
    public static readonly NSString Key = new NSString("MyCell");

    public MyCell(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    {
        this.DelayBind(() => {
            var set = this.CreateBindingSet<MyCell, SomeModelClass>();
            set.Bind(Label1).To(item => item.Label1);
            set.Bind(Label2).To(item => item.Label2);
            set.Apply();
        });
    }

    public static MyCell Create()
    {
        return (MyCell)Nib.Instantiate(null, null)[0];
    }
}
```

My *ViewDidLoad()* in the View looks something like this:

```
CollectionView.RegisterNibForCell(MyCell.Nib, MyCell.Key);
var source = new MvxCollectionViewSource(CollectionView, MyCell.Key);
CollectionView.Source = source;

var set = this.CreateBindingSet<MyView, MyViewModel>();
set.Bind(source).To(vm => vm.ListOfStuff);
set.Apply();

CollectionView.ReloadData();
```

NB! The **ListOfStuff** shown above is really just a List of a custom class containing 2 strings right now.

**TL:DR:** I don't know *ListOfStuff*'s values the moment I call the above code. When I hard-code them in the ViewModel, I get joy. If I don't, I don't, even as data gets updated correctly later.

I now reach out to you, the neurons of the brain of crowdsourcing...

Comment: It seems to be working with:

Comment: source.ReloadOnAllItemsSourceSets = true;

called!!!

I called it earlier too and it didn't work, but I think my Cell sizes were incorrect then and these things just fail to render anything sometimes without error and the like.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a `List<T>` use `ObservableCollection<T>` and new items should be added to the `CollectionView`.

The UI needs to know when the collection has changed. `ObservableCollection<T>` implements `INotifyCollectionChanged` and `INotifyPropertyChanged` and communicates with the UI when the collection changes.

You shouldn't need `ReloadData()` anymore if you're using `ObservableCollection<T>`.

This extension method might be of use when adding range of `IEnumerable<T>`

```
public static class ObservableCollectionExtensionMethod
{
    public static void AddRange<TSource>(this ObservableCollection<TSource> source, IEnumerable<TSource> collection)
    {
        foreach (var i in collection) source.Add(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response, Pilatus! I'll give that a go :)